# myFile.delete(); does not delete file properly android

Tags: android, image, file

I have a piece of code which basically crops an image selected by the user and is supposed to overwrite the image "CurrentProfilePic.jpg" with the new image.It does so by first deleting the image if it exists and then creating it again.but the image doesnt get deleted.So the no. of times the code is run, that many no. of images are created WITH THE SAME NAME. I used logs to see if the file.delete(); returns true, and it does return true.

```
public void cropImage(View v) {
    bitmap=cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
boolean imageSaved = false;
String imageName="CurrentProfilePic";
//to save current image to directory
    if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        File storagePath = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SimpleMessaging/");

        if (!storagePath.exists()) {
            storagePath.mkdirs();
        }
        File temp= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SimpleMessaging/CurrentProfilePic.jpg");
        if(temp.exists()){
            boolean x= temp.delete();
            Log.d("PICS", "Inside if exist of pic");
            if(x)
                Log.d("bool", "x true");
            else
                Log.d("bool", "x false");
        }
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        File imageFile = new File(storagePath, String.format("%s.jpg",
                imageName));


        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            imageSaved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                    100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SaveToSD ", "Unable to write the image to gallery" + e);

        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
        values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, imageName);
        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put("_data", imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

        getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    }
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), EditProfilePic.class));
    finish();
}
```

The thing to stress upon is that the latest image is overwritten on each of those files, but their sizes are unchanged, their original sizes.

Comment: "that many no. of images are created WITH THE SAME NAME" -- by definition, you cannot have two or more files in one directory with the same name.

Comment: @CommonsWare i am well aware of that, but i was shocked to see this. here's a link of a screenshot i took of the directory: http://postimg.org/image/4quomv603/

Comment: And when you checked on the device itself, via DDMS or **`adb shell`**, what did you see?

Comment: i used terminal emulator and used the ls command on the directory.it showed only 1 file! then how is it possible that windows explorer shows multiple??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);` and its supporting code. [Use `MediaScannerConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) or [`ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) to index your file.